# F# and WCF consumption

Tags: c#, wcf, f#, asynchronous

I created a lib in C# with standard "Add Service Reference" dialog but methods which are implemented in it return void so i can't bind to them in async workflows. I can't use the interface with Begin* End* because every method has different number of parameters so it says "Wrong parameters count" (something like that). So how can I consume WCF services asynchronously(async because it's intended to be used in silverlight where everything is async)?

Comment: "return void so I can't bind them in async workflows" - what do you mean?

Comment: I meant how do I can get the result using let!

Comment: What result?  They return void?

Comment: When using svcutil it generates all the async operation as void and the result is returned in callback func, so I could not undestand how to get the result, but in the morning all became clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am unclear what the stumbling block is, but the process should be

- have svcutil generate async interfaces (with Begin/End methods)
- use those methods with `FromBeginEnd` to convert to async: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340508.aspx
- note that if the method returns `void` (`unit`) then you'll be using `do!` rather than `let!` inside an async workflow

Comment: How do I use FromBeginEnd if the Begin* function takes some parameters?

Comment: You're going to have to post a little code that doesn't work, I'm not understanding you.

Comment: Sorry, it was late night and I had a terrible tooth ache, I didn't read the link you provided carefully and missed that I can pass args as first param.

Answer (score 2):

To answer one part of your question: *"How do I use FromBeginEnd if the Begin function takes some parameters?"*

You can do it through the magic of closures. Here's some examples. As you can see, the extension method takes the parameter, but passes to `Async.FromBeginEnd` an anonymous function that matches the signature expected by `FromBeginEnd`. The extra parameter is captured in a closure and passed into the real `BeginXyz` inside the anonymous function.

You can also use the overload of `FromBeginEnd` that takes the additional parameters first, and then the pointers to the Begin/End functions last, as I did in the `AsyncGetReadStream` method below - but when there are multiple overloads of `BeginXyz` I had trouble getting this to work, so I resorted to using closures for most of them.

```
open System
open System.Data.Services.Client

type System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext with

    member this.AsyncExecute<'a> (uri:Uri) =
        Async.FromBeginEnd((fun (cb, state) -> this.BeginExecute<'a>(uri, cb, state)), 
                           (fun iar -> this.EndExecute<'a>(iar) :?> QueryOperationResponse<'a>))

    member this.AsyncExecute<'a> (continuation:DataServiceQueryContinuation<'a>) =
        Async.FromBeginEnd((fun (cb, state) -> this.BeginExecute<'a>(continuation, cb, state)), 
                           (fun iar -> this.EndExecute<'a>(iar) :?> QueryOperationResponse<'a>))

    member this.AsyncExecuteBatch ([<ParamArray>] queries : DataServiceRequest[]) =
        Async.FromBeginEnd((fun (cb, state) -> this.BeginExecuteBatch(cb, state, queries)), this.EndExecuteBatch)

    member this.AsyncLoadProperty (entity:obj, propertyName:string) =
        Async.FromBeginEnd((fun (cb, state) -> this.BeginLoadProperty(entity, propertyName, cb, state)), 
                           this.EndLoadProperty)

    member this.AsyncLoadProperty (entity:obj, propertyName:string, continuation:DataServiceQueryContinuation) =
        Async.FromBeginEnd((fun (cb, state) -> this.BeginLoadProperty(entity, propertyName, continuation, cb, state)), 
                           this.EndLoadProperty)

    member this.AsyncLoadProperty (entity:obj, propertyName:string, nextLinkUri:Uri) =
        Async.FromBeginEnd((fun (cb, state) -> this.BeginLoadProperty(entity, propertyName, nextLinkUri, cb, state)), 
                           this.EndLoadProperty)

    member this.AsyncSaveChanges () =
        Async.FromBeginEnd(this.BeginSaveChanges, this.EndSaveChanges)

    member this.AsyncSaveChanges (options:SaveChangesOptions) =
        Async.FromBeginEnd((fun (cb, state) -> this.BeginSaveChanges(options, cb, state)), 
                           this.EndSaveChanges)

    member this.AsyncGetReadStream (entity:obj, args:DataServiceRequestArgs) =
        Async.FromBeginEnd(entity, args, this.BeginGetReadStream, this.EndGetReadStream)


type System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery with

    member this.AsyncExecute () =
        Async.FromBeginEnd(this.BeginExecute, this.EndExecute)
```